# Backbone not sending PUT to server

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I am having trouble with trying to get backbone to send a PUT request out to my rails server on save. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, it is fine with GET requests just not PUT..

Here is the code that is in my view that I use to save my model.

```
e.preventDefault()
$(@el).find('#error_explanation').html ""
data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(this)
setError = false
@model.set(data, error: (model, error) ->
    setError = true
)
@model.save()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me....

Here is what was in my model.

```
validate: ->
  console.log "validating"
  console.log "options: #{options}"
  errors = []
  if(!@.validateEmail(@.get('email')))
    errors.push("Email can't be blank")
  if(!@.validateName(@.get('first_name')))
    errors.push("First name can't be blank")
  if(!@.validateName(@.get('last_name')))
    errors.push("Last name can't be blank")

  return errors
```

This was actually being called when I was trying to save it which I was just trying to call manually. Since I wasn't returning the correct data saying that it was valid/invalid it just was always invalid.

ooops...

-do